# Word 365: Headings without a following-line break, and paragraph to the right

Tags: microsoft-word, office365

I want to achieve a layout in word, where the heading is set to the right of the text body.  I know that I can potentially achieve this by using a table without borders, but I was wondering whether there was a more elegant solution. I would like to manage this using paragraph styles.

```
HEADING         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing
                elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut
                labore et dolore magna  aliquyam erat, sed diam
                voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo
```

Comment: You can use Hanging and set the space as you like to use it click on the arrow near Paragraph Group, Special and click on the arrow Hanging then change by for a wide space

Comment: @SuperSam I'll  try that thanks.

To the downvoter: Why downvote? This should be the appropriate stackexchange site http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/219955/where-should-i-ask-a-question-about-using-microsoft-word

Comment: @SuperSam: how can he achieve to have Heading and normal paragraphs in the same line?

Comment: @data_hope I don't think you can achieve that. A workaround can be to have character formatting for the paragraph next to the heading (so all your example would be just one paragraph, but two different formatting), however that probably won't work well with automatic table of contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with **Style Separators** (`Ctrl+Alt+Return`).
Table of Contents still work properly.
In your case, do the following:

1. Format your headings with Hanging=4cm.
2. If you want to number your headings, create a tab stop at 1cm.
3. Create your headings and text in separate paragraphs:

   ```
   HEADING

   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed
   diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna
   aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
   ```
4. Go into the heading and press `Ctrl+Alt+Return`.
   This inserts a **Style Separator**.
   If this doesn't work,
   put "Style Separator" into your Quick Access Toolbar
   and use it from there ([See this post](https://office-watch.com/2021/style-separators-in-word/)).
5. Insert a `Tab` after the style separator.
6. **Your document should now look [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtJT5.png).**

Unfortunately, I could not find an official Microsoft help page, so [this](https://smawins.com/news/using-microsoft-word-style-separator/) is my source.

Answer (score 1):

Write the text normally Heading followed by the text(no need to separate the text just like any paragraph) then select both (Heading and text) and use `Page Layout, Column, Left` then `insert Column Break` after the Heading directly, I have try it see the picture below.

[image]

If you have other Headings do the same but only each Heading with the corresponding text should be selected each time or maybe using Column Break will help.

Answer (score -1):

Use text boxes to achieve this.

- What you need to do is to adjust the margin to accommodate the heading. To do this, go to the Page Layout tab, select "Margin", "Custom" margin and add a wider margin for the page where you can freely insert your text box.
- Next, draw a text box. From the Insert tab, select "Text Box" and then from the bottom of the drop down menu, select "Draw Text Box". Draw a text box in the margin that you have created. In the text box, set the style to Heading 1 and type your heading.
- Finally, you need to remove the borders of the text box. From the Format tab, in the Shape Styles section, select "Shape Outline" and remove the outline.